# Is "VNFeaturePrintObservation" and vision distance computation different for two images in two different iOS versions like iOS 16.0 and iOS 17.0?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-vision

I'm trying to know how similar two images are. For that, I'm using **VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest** and generating a **VNFeaturePrintObservation** from an image. Then for the two different images, I'm computing feature distance by using their **VNFeaturePrintObservation**. Unfortunately, computed distances are different for iOS 16.0 and iOS 17.0 thus failing my threshold value.

I tried to get featurePrintObservation for images like below,

```
let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])       
    let request = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()
       do {               
          try requestHandler.perform([request])              
          self.feature = request.results?.first
        } catch {
            print("Vision error: \(error)")
       }
```

Then I tried to compute distance between two feature like below,

```
try! feature1.computeDistance(&visionDistance, to: feature2)
```

The output result "visionDistance" is different for iOS 16.0 and iOS 17.0 for the same two images (For example, '**22.66224**' in iOS 16.3.1 and '**1.2178229**' in iOS 17.0.1).  I want to know if **VNFeaturePrintObservation** has changed in iOS 17.0 or not, and if changed then is there any way to generalize the calculation for both of the iPhone operating systems?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem

Comment: I am also facing this issue. It is very annoying.

Answer (score 6):

A colleage and I wrote a detailed article about `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest` and the differences between iOS16 and iOS17 (you can find it [on Medium](https://medium.com/@MWM.io/apples-vision-framework-exploring-advanced-image-similarity-techniques-f7bb7d008763)).

To sum up the differences:

- On iOS16, a `VNFeaturePrintObservation` is a **non-normalized** vector containing 2048 `Float`.
- On iOS17, it's a **normalized** vector having length 768.

Also, the `computeDistance(_:to:)` method computes the straightforward euclidian distance between those vectors.

As a consequence:

- On iOS17, the distance between two observations is always less than 2.0.
- On iOS16, the distance can vary a lot; typical values range between 0.0 and 40.0.

So, yes, this change can be quite annoying. Note that you can reproduce the iOS16 behavior on iOS17 by setting the `revision` property of a `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest` instance to `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequestRevision1` (distance values will not be exactly the same though, you'll get slight, non-significant differences).

If you have to support only iOS17, I would recommend to prefer the iOS17 `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequestRevision2` algorithm, since comparing normalized vectors makes much more sense (the distance between normalized vectors is closely related to their *cosine distance*, a popular measure of vector similarity in data analysis).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We have already set "revision" property to use previous algorithm and fixed the issue, we need to provide support for iOS 16 too.